# GstBuffer Pixel Type (Determining BPP)

Tags: c, gstreamer

I am trying to write a GStreamer (0.10.34) plugin.  I need manipulate an incoming image.  I have my Sink caps set as "video/x-raw-yuv" so I know I'll be getting video.

I am having trouble in understanding how to use the GstBuffer, more specifically:

- How do I get the bits per pixel?
- Given the bpp, how do I determine the dimensions of the buffer?

I am currently elbows deep in 0.10.34 core documentation reading about GstStructure and GstQuarks... I think I'm in the wrong area.

As always, thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some source code hunting (jpegenc), I found the BaseLib plugins, most importantly GstVideo.  This gives you the function `gst_video_format_parse_caps`

GstVideoFormat seems to be what you use to parse incoming video information.